# Can anyone help me to understand this line of code in lua

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

```
local match1 = string.match(sk, "state = <string>%s*%d+")
```

In this variable 'sk' is a string. I didn't understand what is meant by `<string>` in the given pattern that is to be matched.

Comment: It is to be taken literally. The string `sk` is expected to contain `<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

`"state = <string>%s*%d+"` is a string like any other string.

`%s*%d+` have special meanings here but `<string>` is just that literal string.

This pattern will match `"state <string>"` followed by 0 or more whitespace characters, followed by one or more digit.

for example

```
local sk = "hello world, state = <string>    24 dogs eat a cat"
print(string.match(sk, "state = <string>%s*%d+"))
```

would print `state = <string>    24`